# Broadcast variable in spark causing performance issue

Tags: performance, apache-spark, bigdata, azure-databricks

I have a cluster where we have 8 nodes. Each has 116 GB ram and 16 core and I am trying to read table X which is 250 GB in size. Table X I am joining with table Y 10 times to derive 10 columns. The size of table Y is 100 MB.

Now my question is when I am broadcasting table Y and explicitly caching the table y, script takes around 20 hours but when I am not caching and only broadcasting the table y the complete process took only 1 hour.

Unable to understand what is actually causing more time if we explicitly cache 100 MB after broadcasting the table.

Tried searching on official documentation but could not much information.

Please help.

Comment: This is not enough information. spark-submit , spark-ui details and the code which you are using how you are doing... etc matters a lot.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram Code is something I can not share as it is at my work place  but just to give you the picture the table X which I am using has 350 columns and I am joining on the basis of only one column but 10 times that join is happening with table y. Since this complete processing happening on databricks so need not to explicitly mention the memory and cores for the executors.